# Get Sender info from GestureRecognizer tied to multi UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, sender

So I have a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` connected to

```
@IBAction func PresentPlayerInfo(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    if let button = sender.view as? UIButton {
        buttonSourceFrame = button.frame.origin}
    performSegueWithIdentifier("PVC", sender: self)
}
```

`buttonSourceFrame` is then passed to next ViewController in `prepareForSegue`

I want to connect this 1 `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to multiple `UIButton`s so that I don't have to create a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for each `UIButton`.

But when I connect more than one `UIButton` to a single gestureRecognizer...No matter which button I press, the segue occurs fine but the `CGPoint` that's passed is always that of which ever `UIButton` is at the top of the list (here it's 3), instead of the `CGPoint` of the exact `UIButton` pressed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltiKb.png)

**Is it possible to connect a `GestureRecognizer` to many `UIButton`s and still get sender info...or do I HAVE to create a `GestureRecognizer` each `UIButton`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the gesture recognizer to the main view of your viewController. Then, in your `@IBAction` you have to determine the view which was tapped:

```
@IBAction func PresentPlayerInfo(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    var tappedView: UIView?
    var loc = sender.locationInView(self.view)  // self.view is the parent view of the buttons

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button1.frame, loc)) {
        tappedView = self.button1
    }
    else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button2.frame, loc)) {
        tappedView = self.button2
    }


    performSegueWithIdentifier("PVC", sender: tappedView)
}
```

Comment: I had to change `var tappedView: UIView?` to ` var tappedView = UIView()` and declare it outside of `@IBAction` method so that I could reference it in `prepareForSegue`, But this worked, Ty

Comment: I have set the `sender` in `performSegueWithIdentifier` to the tappedView in my example above so the tapped button is passed from `performSegueWithIdentifier` to `prepareForSegue`

Comment: gotcha, i see that now

Answer (score 0):

A `gestureRecognizer` has only one `view` property, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view). It is usual to create a separate one for each UI element where you want the gesture recognized. If you wish to create a single recognizer and then work out which button has been pressed, you need to attach the recognizer to a single view encompassing all your buttons, and then work out the location of the press with (say) `locationInView`, taking into account the effects of any autolayout changes. Personally, I'd just create all the separate recognizers.